# Combine Gabor filter results in java without OpenCV

Tags: java, image-processing, gabor-filter

Im working on Gabor Filter and have a problem. For example i have an image and compute the results of Gabor Filtering with a bank of 4 (or more) filters (theta). So, i will get a 4 different images. How can i merge/combine them together to aquire 1 image (smth. like: Core.addWeighted(), but without OpenCV). 
Any code examples would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show what you have so far

Comment: I dont inderstand why do u ask that, bro. My code works well. I just need any ideas (or maybe someone knows exact what to do) at "combine" stage. An average for 4 pixels like (pix1+pix2+pix3+pix4)/4 doest work for me. As i undestood i need to calculate weigthed summ for each pixel in 4 arrays or smth like that. Plz post here any links or docs if u know any info.